# (how to) Change back to Win + N shortcut in OneNote 2013 to create new Quick Note?

Tags: keyboard-shortcuts, microsoft-office-2013, microsoft-onenote-2013

I found similar questions for former versions of OneNote, but none for the 2013 version. They changed the shortcut from <kbd>Win</kbd>+<kbd>N</kbd> to create a new Quick Note to <kbd>Win</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>N</kbd> which is much less convenient to use. How can one swap the <kbd>Win</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>N</kbd> and <kbd>Win</kbd>+<kbd>N</kbd> shortcuts?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I know this is old, but this was a really infuriating change Microsoft made. I get that it is due to competing internal teams and Windows > OneNote/Office, but still...  I used <kbd>Win</kbd>+<kbd>N</kbd> daily, as did a lot of people.

Anyway, here's what I did to "fix the glitch":

1. Installed [AutoHotkey](http://www.autohotkey.com/) (Freeware scriptable key remapping software)
2. In the default script file it creates in your `Documents` folder: `AutoHotKey.ahk` I added the following: `#n::#!n`

That basically says:  <kbd>#</kbd><kbd>n</kbd> [<kbd>Win</kbd>+<kbd>N</kbd>] = [<kbd>Win</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>N</kbd>]

Save, then hit the reload script from the tasktray menu for AutoHotkey and viola, SOLVED! Omg finally... geez that one was killin me for ages.

Now reap the benefits of AutoHotkey... because holy crap that is an awesome app.  I'm only 15min in, but I have already added a ton of frequently used things to it including even code blocks for when I dev Lol.  I love it.

Anyway, hope this helps you if still needed, and if for nothing else, the next google searcher such as myself. :)

Comment: Hi, thanks, I know AutoHotKey and I use it myself for a while now. However, by the time I got to know it I got used to the win + alt + n alternative, so I do not even think about it anymore. However, this answer might be useful for others, who did not get used to it, so I will accept it, since it does work around it well.

Answer (score 0):

With Microsoft's Power Toys, you can use the Keyboard Manager plugin and redirect WIN+N to WIN+ALT+N, effectively providing the same result of launching a Quick Note.

[Keyboard Manager - Remap a shortcut](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lV16E.png)

Comment: Thanks. I no longer use OneNote, but I hope people will find your answer helpful.

Comment: Thank you @Ev0oD, that's my intention too. I know this thread is old, and there may be users who won't prefer getting into complex scripting program like AutoHotKey, so this may help someone :)